# Appengine Datastore api deprecation reagrding

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Can you please confirm if com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query and QueryResultIterator and Cursor are deprecated? Google site says if using the datastore package, then replace it with DatastoreServiceConfig instead But no details of how to implement? How do I replace the above packages with DatastoreServiceConfig? Any samples will be useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the current documentation these classes are not marked as deprecated:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/Query

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/QueryResultIterator

Comment: You may accept this answer if it solves your problem.